# Average time from DateTime dataset in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, average

I am trying to get the avg time a driver completed a delivery stops at each unique customer. I am using the following columns:

```
Name (varchar(50))
Reference1 (varchar(50))
CompletedTime (Datetime).
```

I am getting an avg but it includes the date & time NOT just date. Which is making the time avg incorrect.

thanks for the help!

**Current Code Below:**

```
select name, Reference1, CAST(AVG(CAST(CompletedTime AS float)) AS datetime)
From tblOrderRouteStops
where Name not like 'Cta%' and Reference1 <> '000000' and Name <> '' and CompletedTime is not Null
Group By name, Reference1
```

**Data Set:**

```
CASCADE HEMOPHILIA CONSORTIUM   000117  2010-10-01 09:24:01.000
CASCADE HEMOPHILIA CONSORTIUM   000117  2010-09-29 09:30:23.000
CASCADE HEMOPHILIA CONSORTIUM   000117  2010-09-27 09:44:17.000
CASCADE HEMOPHILIA CONSORTIUM   000117  2010-09-24 09:36:49.000
CASCADE HEMOPHILIA CONSORTIUM   000117  2010-09-23 09:48:20.000
CASCADE HEMOPHILIA CONSORTIUM   000117  2010-09-22 09:21:20.000
BOTSFORD OUT-PATIENT PHARMACY   006106  2010-09-23 08:01:06.000
BOTSFORD OUT-PATIENT PHARMACY   006106  2010-09-22 08:02:42.000
BOTSFORD OUT-PATIENT PHARMACY   006106  2010-09-24 08:21:36.000
BOTSFORD OUT-PATIENT PHARMACY   006106  2010-09-27 08:24:49.000
BOTSFORD OUT-PATIENT PHARMACY   006106  2010-09-28 08:25:58.000
BOTSFORD GENERAL HOSPITAL PREM  006205  2010-10-04 07:33:13.000
BOTSFORD GENERAL HOSPITAL PREM  006205  2010-10-01 07:35:13.000
BOTSFORD GENERAL HOSPITAL PREM  006205  2010-09-30 07:31:15.000
BOTSFORD GENERAL HOSPITAL PREM  006205  2010-09-29 07:41:56.000
BOTSFORD GENERAL HOSPITAL PREM  006205  2010-09-28 08:03:38.000
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Name, Reference1, Time
```

Comment: Can you post, say, 10 rows of sample data?

Comment: what output do you need?

Comment: both requested added to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wil work for you

You can get rid of the dateby using convert(varchar,Value,108)

```
select name, Reference1,
    CONVERT(varchar,  CAST(AVG(CAST(CompletedTime AS float) - CAST(CompletedTime AS int)) AS datetime),108) averageTime
        From tblOrderRouteStops
        where Name not like 'Cta%' and Reference1 <> '000000' and Name <> '' and CompletedTime is not Null
        Group By name, Reference1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your float approach was a good start: you need to remove the whole number which gives you a fraction representing time of day. Average that, change back to datetime. To use this, ignore the "01 jan 1900" and take the time bit as your average

```
select name, Reference1,
          CAST(AVG(CAST(CompletedTime AS float) - CAST(CompletedTime AS int)) AS datetime)
From tblOrderRouteStops
where Name not like 'Cta%' and Reference1 <> '000000' and Name <> '' and CompletedTime is not Null
Group By name, Reference1
```

Comment: I am getting "1900-01-01 08:05:41.000" as the avg.  any way to drop the date?

Comment: @user466118: sorry, no. it's a "datetime" value so you'll always have a date component

Comment: gbh thanks... i took what you started and added a convert to get only the time part.   select name,Convert(nvarchar,CAST(AVG(CAST(CompletedTime AS float) - CAST(CompletedTime AS int)) AS datetime),108)

Comment: you can use convert(varchar,datetimeValue,108)